# Web Analytics for knowledge base articles

Tags: google-analytics

Like most companies, our support team has a help page/knowledge base available online. We've got Google Analytics setup on the site as a whole and I'd like to start better utilizing the tools available for optimizing the Help pages. However, most of the literature on web analytics focuses on sales and conversions where as in a Support page our goals are quite different. Specifically, we want to reduce incoming support requests.

Can anyone advise in the types of things we should be monitoring or where to go for more information?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you've already set up Google Analytics in a standard way to track pageviews for your knowledge base...you already have it set to see # visitors to each page. That's step zero.

I always start by asking the question, "What is the job we hired (the website, or website section) to do?" Then you can go about defining metrics. You've already said it's job is to reduce incoming support requests, so you need to track that. Assuming you take support requests online:

- I'd set up an Event every
  time someone files a request. You want to see how changes to your
  knowledge base makes that number go down.
- Many sites have sort of a workflow when filing new requests. First users browse the knowledge base, then go to a form to ask their specific question, then see a confirmation page. In Google Analytics you track a flow through a set of predefined steps with a [Goal Funnel](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en)
- Do you care about segmenting knowledge base/support requestors? Customers vs. non-customers? Logged in vs not-logged in? You can tag [users or sessions with custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables?csw=1) to give you additional segmentation powers.
- You may want to look at Google's new [Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) feature. That may allow you   to track visits across your knowledge base as a single entity, and watch views go up or down

Tracking support that comes in via phone/offline is trickier. But with the Universal Analytics in public beta, [you can now upload custom data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). So you could really upload CRM or call center data into Google Analytics.